# Can't convert Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
# Note: Return a string of 2 decimal places.
def Cel2Fah(temp): 
    fah = float((temp*9/5)+32)
    fah_two = (%.2f) % fah
    fah_string = str(fah_two)
    return fah_string
```

Here's what I should get:

```
>>> Cel2Fah(28.0)
    '82.40'
>>> Cel2Fah(0.00)
    '32.00'
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Code", line 4
fah_two = (%.2f) % fah
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what is going on...

This doesn't seem to work either for some reason:

```
# Note: Return a string of 2 decimal places.
def Cel2Fah(temp): 
    fah = temp*9/5+32
    fah_cut = str(fah).split()
    while len(fah_cut) > 4:
        fah_cut.pop()
    fah_shorter = fah_cut
    return fah_shorter
```

Comment: convert `temp` to float before doing the math or use float literals for the constants (Python won't auto-convert result to float unless there is a float in the operation).

Comment: What is `(%.2f) % fah` supposed to mean?

Comment: @PauloScardine: In Python 3, `/` is always floating point division (however, it's unclear whether the OP is using Python 2 or Python 3).

Comment: @GregHewgill: I was not aware of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sucmac:~ ajung$ cat x.py 
def toF(cel):
    return '%.2f' % (cel * 1.8 +32)

print toF(0)
print toF(50)
print toF(100)

sucmac:~ ajung$ python x.py 
32.00
122.00
212.00
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want:

```
fah_two = "%.2f" % fah
```

The result of the `%` formatting operator is a string, so you don't need `fah_string` because `fah_two` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Further, I think `temp * 9 / 5` should be `temp * 9 / 5.0`.

Comment: That wouldn't matter if `temp` is a `float` as seems to be the case there, but it might be surprising if someone passes an `int` to the function.

Comment: In Python 3, `/` is always floating point division (however, it's unclear whether the OP is using Python 2 or Python 3).